# Git: How to manage multiple branches on submodule and tie them to particular branches on main repo

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I am working on a large project where the main repository as well as the submodule are rapidly changing. Currently there is only one submodule which has different branches. Lets call them master, dev1 and dev2. The main repository also has various branches like master, dev1, dev2, dev3, dev4 etc. Now I know that when I checkout a branch on main repository the submodule will be checked out at a particular commit in detached HEAD. Having multiple branches in submodule force me to always remember to checkout right branches on main repository as well submodule before making any commits to main repo or submodule. What I want is when I checkout a particular branch on main repository, the branch with a matching name should be automatically checked out on submodule and if there is no matching branch, the 'master' branch on the submodule should be checked out. I want the same thing to happen while switching branches on submodule too so that the appropriate branch on main repo has the appropriate commit on the relevant branch on submodule.

Git 1.8.2 added an option to track submodule as a branch. I am not able to figure out if this is useful anyways to achieve what I want.

Please let me know if it seems possible any other way. Also it would be great to know how you folk usually manage this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need to do is move the sub-module to a separate repository and use it as an external in the main repository, you can then tag specific versions, (and branches), of the external in the main and vice versa.